# Log to file the memory usage (Private Bytes) of a process

Tags: logging, memory-management

I have a process that I'm monitoring, using Process Explorer. I'm periodically viewing the Private Bytes Performance Graph. I can't check the graph overnight, but I'd like a record of its memory consumption. What I'd like to be able to do is like to a file every say 30 seconds, the following

PID | Time stamp | Private Bytes (snapshot)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Performance Monitor* MMC console (perfmon.msc) supports background data collection.

1. Open the "Data Collector Sets → User Defined" branch. Right-click to create a new set.
2. Select "Create manually". In the next page, choose "Create data logs" and enable "Performance counter" logging.
3. Click "Add Counter" and select "Process → Private Bytes" from the available counters list. You'll be able to select from running process names as "instances" of the counter.

   (Note that if you have multiple processes with the same basename, they'll have individual instances named "foo#2", "foo#3" etc.)
4. Apparently *that's* what the C:\PerfLogs directory is for.
5. Select "Start this data collector set now".
6. After some time, right-click the collector set (the whole set, not the specific collector) and choose "Latest Report". This should open a scrollable graph, similar to the live "Performance Monitor" view.

(I don't know how well this works, I literally just figured out how to use it 15 minutes ago.)

Comment: We have multiple instances of the same service name running from different directories, so they show as `servicename#1`, `servicename#2` which means I can't pin-point which one to monitor. I am still going to mark this as the correct answer though, as the steps would be correct if my service name wasn't recycled > 30 times on the same machine.

Comment: @spikey_richie: Just monitor them all then, I think there is a "counter" that reports the process' PID as the value so you can discard the incorrect ones afterwards. Also wouldn't be surprised if the instance *could* be a PID, but this probably needs one of the command-line event tracing tools to be used instead.